# ASP.Net Core MVC: лучший способ создания индекса сообщений в БД EFC

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

уважаемые товарищи!
Пишу небольшой форум в ASP.Net Core (.Net 5 (возможно далее мигрирую на .Net 6)).
Есть модель сообщений:

```
public class ForumMessageModel
    {
        #region Позиционирование сообщения
        /// <summary>
        /// Идентификатор сообщения
        /// </summary>
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Идентификатор темы
        /// </summary>
        public int TopicID { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Номер сообщения в теме
        /// </summary>
        public ulong MessageNum { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Сообщение
        /// <summary>
        /// Ссылка на сообщение-родитель (это сообщение -- ответ)
        /// </summary>
        public int ReplyTo { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Сообщение
        /// </summary>
        public string Text { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Meta-данные сообщения
        /// <summary>
        /// Дата публикации
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// ID автора
        /// </summary>
        public string Author { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Дата последнего изменения
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Благодарности
        /// <summary>
        /// Благодарности (в формате зашифрованного JSON)
        /// </summary>
        public string Thanks { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
```

Как вы поняли, наверняка, из модели Id текущее в типе int (что прекрасно генерируется EFCore 5.0.11, в отличие от ulong).

А теперь, собственно, проблема: при увеличении числа сообщений (а люди оочень любят трепаться по делу и нет) рано или поздно, int исчерпает себя. Понятное дело, что мне хочется обезопасить проект, чтобы потом не пришлось переписывать. Вопрос: в каком типе и как лучше создавать индекс, чтобы и EFCore сам создавал его, и этой ошибки не было.

Смотрю на Мелкософт: он в identity ставит string-овские ID. Может их? Тогда как их генерировать?

И ещё, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, хороший и бесплатный Markdown-редактор для проекта.

Спасибо!

Comment: Ставьте метку языка (c#). Возможно из-за её отсутствие вопрос остался незамеченным.

Comment: Если `int` недостаточно (а это два миллиарда значений), используйте `long`. Или `Guid`.

Comment: Не задавайте несколько вопросов в одной теме. PS: просьбы с поиском софта и т. п. не приветствуются на этом сайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Key , DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID
2^128 вариантов, более чем достаточно

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо большое.